# How can I log the GPS use of Android Apps?

Tags: android, logging, gps

I want to create an application, that runs in the background, and monitors the other running Apps.

Can you tell me, how do I know when an App acces to the GPS, so I can insert the name of the App and the time interval into a sqlite database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do I know when an App acces to the GPS

You don't, at least on a standard Android device. I cannot rule out the possibility of determining this on a rooted device or as a system app, though I am not aware of any specific options for those scenarios either.

Generally speaking, one app has no means to spy on the operations of another app. There are some specific exceptions to this, though they tend to get locked down over time.

Comment: This does not sound good. How hard is a write system app like this? Where can I learn it? Or should I drop this project? (It's part of my thesis.)

Comment: @BlackCat: "How hard is a write system app like this? Where can I learn it?" -- by system app, I mean one that is installed on the `/system` partition, which either occurs because the user rooted their device and moved the app there, or the user installed a ROM mod that had the app. But I have no idea if GPS spying is even possible then. The only absolutely certain way to do it would involve you creating your own ROM mod, where you add to Android the hooks to enable this sort of spying.